# Should one avoid including regular Javascript objects in AngularJS controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm reading Pro AngularJS by Adam Freeman, and I have a nitpicky question concerning one of the book's examples:

```
myApp.controller("tomorrowCtrl", function($scope) {
    var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday";]
    $scope.day = dayNames[(new Date().getDay() + 1) % 7];    
});
```

I understand what this controller's overall purpose is: to show the name of the day of the week on the view via `$scope.day`.  But I'm confused about why the controller is using an ordinary Javascript array - `var dayNames` - to create the `$scope` object.

The [AngularJS controller documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) explains that controllers are used to:

> set up the initial state of the $scope object [and to] add behavior to the $scope object.

And sure enough, `dayNames` helps set up the initial state of the $scope object.  It also contains a bit of the application's business logic, so I guess it sort of checks out.  My worry is that I haven't found any other examples of AngularJS controllers that follow this design pattern; I haven't found anything in the Angular controller docs, nor the PhoneCat tutorial.

Does it make sense to include ordinary Javascript objects in AngularJS controllers like this? (Is this considered harmless?)

If not, why?  Are there any good reasons to *not* include ordinary Javascript objects in controllers? Also, is there a different way that `dayNames` should fit into the Angular schema, like a directive or a service?

Comment: I guess they have no reason to expose dayNames so they're not binding it to $scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see plenty of examples like that in books & the internet. The point is that the `$scope.day` is set to *something* and I'm sure how it reflects it within your `view`.

You can have external plain Javascript logic and use it within angularJS, it obviously won't *break* anything, but typically it's good practice to have ALL scope manipulation / business logic done outside of the controller in a service/factory/provider. Why go against angularJS and use external things? You want to stick within angularJS's flow.

Let's say it was doing something much more complicated, it would of probably looked more like this:

```
myApp.factory("tomorrowService", function() {
    // factory's can be written in many different patterns
    // this is just for examples sake
    return {
        getDays : function () { /* return stuff */ }
    }
});

myApp.controller("tomorrowCtrl", function($scope, tomorrowService) {
    $scope.day = tomorrowService.getDays();    
});
```

With a method within `tomorrowService` doing all the business logic and returning some sort of result.

I found this article (http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/) very imformative to help get a better idea of how to make your controllers and the separation that is beneficial within an angularJS project.

Comment: And to nitpick, it should properly be named `tomorrowService` - the factory is only the function that generates the instance of the service :)

Comment: I typed too quickly. You win :) Fixed @NewDev

Answer (score 1):

1. Does this data belong only in that controller and nowhere else in
   the app?
2. Does this data directly support the generation of the View Model (as opposed to a business logic)?
3. Does this create a "fat" controller (i.e. makes the code hard to follow)?

(I don't know if the list is comprehensive)

If the answers are "no", then it's probably OK to keep it there.

Not everything has to be on the $scope. I sometimes see this in questions:

```
$scope.init = function(){
  // do some initialization
}

$scope.init();
```

Clearly, there was no reason to attach `init` onto the scope and would be better declared as a named function defined in the controller:

```
function init(){
}

init();
```